# How to open a div and close another div when a object is pushed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking for some more help with some javascript! I have been messing around with what I already have to try and expand it and I can't get anything to work! Anyways let me explain! There will be a demo below for you to see what I am talking about!

Right now If you press the yellow, black, or red button; A window will pop out. If you have the window from the black button open and press the red button, the window from the black button will slide back and the window from the red button will come out. Now here is my problem! If you click on the black button; there is a gray box! If you click the gray box; another window will open with a green box! Now this window with the green box in it, is where I am stuck! The window with the green box will not react with any other buttons. While this window is open, you can click the red, black, or yellow button and nothing will happen. So what I want to do is make the window with the green box react with all the other buttons and close and open whatever other window you want to open.

There is one more thing I would like to know also! There is a purple box in the same window as the green box! I want that to be a "back" button. So once you click the purple button it will revert back to the previous window you were at!

I am still really new to javascript and I am having a lot of trouble getting the hang of it completely! If anybody could please help! I would really appreciate it!

Here is some code!

HTML

```
<div id="sidemenu">
  <div id="home" class="not-open regionsButton">
    <div id="homeTooltip"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="regionsContainer">
    <div id="regionsUnitedStates" class="not-open regionsButton">
      <div id="regionsUnitedStatesTooltip"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="regionsCanada" class="not-open regionsButton">
      <div id="regionsCanadaTooltip"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="homeContent" class="regionsContent"></div>
  <div id="regionsUnitedStatesChooseState" class="regionsContent">
    <div id="chooseStateUnitedStatesColumnOne">
      <div id="chooseStateAlabama"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="regionsCanadaChooseProvince" class="regionsContent">CDN</div>
</div>
<div id="regionsUnitedStatesAlabamaChooseCity">
  <div id="chooseCityAlabamaAbbeville"></div>
  <div id="chooseCityAlabamaAlabaster"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#home{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ffff00;
}
#homeTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#home.not-open:hover #homeTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#home:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#homeContent {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 19%;
    background: #505759;
    top:60px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
}
#sidemenu {
    width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    transition: left ease-in-out 0.5s;
    top: 0;
}
#sidemenu.show {
    left: 0;
}
#regionsContainer {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
}
#regionsUnitedStates {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#111111;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000;
    height:60px;
    width:180px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsUnitedStates.not-open:hover #regionsUnitedStatesTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsUnitedStates:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanada {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#aa0114;
}
#regionsCanadaTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:60px;
    width:120px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:60px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsCanada.not-open:hover #regionsCanadaTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsCanada:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#chooseStateUnitedStatesColumnOne {
    width:150px;
    height:540px;
    float:left;     
}
#chooseStateAlabama {
    width: 150px;
    height:54px;
    background-color:#999999;
    top:0px;
}
#chooseStateAlabama:hover {
    background-color:#999888;   
    cursor:pointer;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesAlabamaChooseCity {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -750px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 540px;
    background: #505759;
    top: 0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesAlabamaChooseCity.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#chooseCityAlabamaAbbeville {
    width: 150px;
    height:54px;
    background-color:#008000;
    top:0px;
}
#chooseCityAlabamaAbbeville:hover {
    background-position:bottom; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
#chooseCityAlabamaAlabaster {
    width: 150px;
    height:54px;
    background-color:#800080;
    top:54px;
}
#chooseCityAlabamaAlabaster:hover {
    background-position:bottom; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(slideSidemenu) {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#sidemenu").addClass("show") }, 500);
});

var $regionsContent = $('.regionsContent'), 
$regionsButton = $('.regionsButton').click(function(){
    var $button = $(this).removeClass('not-open');
    var buttonIndex = $regionsButton.index($button);
    $regionsContent.removeClass('show');
setTimeout(function() {
    $regionsContent.eq(buttonIndex).addClass('show');
    }, 150);
    $regionsButton.not($button).addClass('not-open');
});

$('#chooseStateAlabama').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.regionsContent').removeClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {       
       $("#regionsUnitedStatesAlabamaChooseCity").addClass('show');
    }, 300);
});

$('#chooseStateAlaska').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.regionsContent').removeClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {       
       $("#regionsUnitedStatesAlaskaChooseCity").addClass('show');
    }, 300);
});
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lbhk/14/)

Comment: `.slideToggle()` might be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (your DOM may use some refactoring to go with a better solution):

Add a `content` class on all of your `.regionsContent`, and `#regionsUnitedStatesAlabamaChooseCity` and `#regionsUnitedStatesAlaskaChooseCity`

Then hide all with a single call before showing anything:

```
$('.content').removeClass('show');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lbhk/24/)